# Moving the HTTP Response responsibility to different methods in a Play Framework REST API

Tags: java, rest, asynchronous, playframework, akka

I'm currently working on a proof of concept for a fully a-synchronous Message based (Akka) REST API. Except I'm already running into some issues with the way the Play framework handles requests. From examples and tutorials it seems like this is the standard setup for a GET Endpoint (Code reduced for code example):

```
public class APIController extends Controller {

    public Result getRecord(int id){
        return ok("ok");
    }
}
```

So the default flow would be, the API endpoint connected method gets found using the Routing file and subsequently called, then it expects a return value of type Result ( or CompletionStage ) which will be used to respond to the HTTP Request source with anything supplied into it.

I'd like to move the responsibility of responding to the request to a different method which is called by my messaging system (using Akka) to make sure every part of it runs in async. So a good example would be the Node.JS way of fixing this, which is passing the actual response variable from the original endpoint function into subsequent messages allowing any step along the way to send a HTTP response without it having to backtrack to the original endpoint function.

I'm wondering if there is any way of accomplishing this same flow as it would in Node.JS

If it's a little vague I'd be happy to try and clear my question up.